# Reading XML file in an offline web application

Tags: javascript, xml, html, offline-web-app

I'm very very new in HTML and JavaScript development.

My goal is to develop a WebWorks Playbook app, but as it is identical to an Offline HTML5 app I ask this:

I want to read an XML file using JavaScript. Because it is an Offline application I don't know how to get access to XML file.

Do you know how can I get access to this XML file?

And then, how can I read it? May I use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5's localStorage to store the XML file in user's browser(as a string).
Then when offline, read it from localStorage.